# add column to groups on dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
  id  |   x   |   y 
   1  |  0.3  |  0.4
   1  |  0.2  |  0.5
   2  |  0.1  |  0.6
   2  |  0.9  |  0.1
   3  |  0.8  |  0.2
   3  |  0.7  |  0.3
```

How can I add a new column to dataframe relative to the id column?

for example:

```
  id  |   x   |   y   |  color
   1  |  0.3  |  0.4  | 'green'
   1  |  0.2  |  0.5  | 'green'
   2  |  0.1  |  0.6  | 'black'
   2  |  0.9  |  0.1  | 'black'
   3  |  0.8  |  0.2  |  'red'
   3  |  0.7  |  0.3  |  'red'
```

Comment: if you have a dictionary like `d={1:'green',2:'black',3:'red'}` , you can do `df['color']=df['id'].map(d)`

Comment: I don't have a dictionary, I have hundreds of IDs, the colors are generated by a function

Comment: how do you know which id gets which color

Comment: What is the function that generate the colors? `df['id'].map(func)` also works with function.

Comment: The colors are generated by a function: def random_color(): return randint(0,255), randint(0,255), randint(0,255)

Comment: probably you need to modify the question with more details on what your function returns based on which how do you want to assign per id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your function doesn't return color names but instead the RGB values, if this it what you want in the color column build the dictionary first from the unique id values and apply the dictionary the way @anky_91 mentioned in the comments.

```
d={x:random_color() for x in df.id.unique()}
df['color']=df['id'].map(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably to late but if you want alternatives, here's another way with a simple function:

```
colors = ['Green', 'Black', 'Red']

def color(data):
    if data['id'] == 1:
        col = colors[0]
    if data['id'] == 2:
        col = colors[1]
    if data['id'] == 3:
        col = colors[2]
    return col

df['Colors'] = df.apply(color, axis = 1)
print(df)

#    id    x    y Colors
# 0   1  0.3  0.4  Green
# 1   1  0.2  0.5  Green
# 2   2  0.1  0.6  Black
# 3   2  0.9  0.1  Black
# 4   3  0.8  0.2    Red
# 5   3  0.7  0.3    Red
```